# Saving h5 model by relative path - Keras tensorflow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

Hey to my beloved community.

How do we save a model to a relative file path using tensorflow embedded keras?

```
    model.save('/models/model.h5')
```

I tried:

```
'./models/'
'/models/'
'models/'
```

Neither seems to work and I always end up with:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): Failed to create a NewWriteableFile:
```

I don't want to provide an absolute path as it might change dynamically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error might be related to one of the reasons below:

- **Do the specified folder exists?** If not, you should make it using:

  ```python
  import os
  os.makedirs('models/')          # Creating a directory
  model.save('models/model.h5')   # Saving model
  ```
- **Do you have permission to write to that folder?** If you are using Unix-based system (i.e. Mac OS or Linux), then you can check it by:

  ```
  ls -l models/
  ```

  A friendly tutorial on Unix file permission can be found [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-file-permission.htm).
- **Does your path contains special symbols?** (i.e. `~` for user's folder) you will need to use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) to resolve the path.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to what @FalconUA mentioned, Here I am providing an example of saving a `tensorflow.keras` model to be saved in `model_path` folder under current directory. This works well with most recent tensorflow (`TF2.0.0rc2`).

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist

#import data
(x_train, y_train),(x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0

# create a model
def create_model():
  model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation=tf.nn.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.nn.softmax)
    ])
# compile the model
  model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

# Create a basic model instance
model=create_model()

model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=1)
loss, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test,verbose=1)
print("Original model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%".format(100*acc))

# Save entire model to a HDF5 file
model.save('./model_path/my_model.h5')

# Recreate the exact same model, including weights and optimizer.
new_model = keras.models.load_model('./model_path/my_model.h5')
loss, acc = new_model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
print("Restored model, accuracy: {:5.2f}%".format(100*acc))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example of a function that responds to the question. If the folder does not exist create a new one else use the existing folder.

```
def save_model(path, model):
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        print('save directories...', flush=True)
        os.makedirs(path)
    model.save(path + '/handrecognition_model.h5')
```